# what is the use of event name with selector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

i have this html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="holder">
    <span class="pressy">press here..!!</span>
    <div class="inner">
        <span class="pressy">press here..!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and js

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown.inner','.pressy',function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

actually i'm getting alert for both the 'pressy' how can i get it only for inner pressy??

and one more thing is what is use of

> 'mousedown.inner'

(not in this. i'm asking about general use) how can i use it correctly??

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ayqqfnm/

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the JS like this:

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown.inner','.inner .pressy',function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Keeping `mousedown.inner` is optional (as @Arun says, it applies to event namespacing) - it isnt necessary here but it doesnt hurt anything.
The second piece, the `.inner .press`y makes it a more specific selector and gets it to ignore your first `.pressy` element

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ayqqfnm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It is called [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names), it is used so that we can target those events individually.

Assume a case where you are adding multiple click handler to a button, then want to remove only one of those handlers, how do you do that? doing `$('button').off('click')` will remove all click handlers added to the button which is not what we want.

So the solution is to use namespaces like

```
$('button').on('click.myevent', function(){...})
```

then if we do

```
$('button').off('click.myevent')
```

it will remove only those click handlers which are added with the namespace `myevent`

Comment: While all this is true, it doesn't answer all parts of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown', '.inner .pressy', function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

In the `on` function it is disregarding the `.` and anything thereafter so I have noved the `.inner` selector to the next argument to target only your intended target.

Comment: @kathirvel The only difference it has is that it gives you the ability to detach the handlers namespaced as `inner`, but in terms of event handling it's not different.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works, one could also do

```
 $('.inner').on('mousedown','.pressy',function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
 })
```

Which as robs snippet targets the pressy class inside .inner

http://jsfiddle.net/9krgu4ge/

Answer (score 0):

The only change you must do is to specify a delegated selector that only cares about `.pressy` within `.inner`, rather than every `.inner`.

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown.inner','.inner .pressy', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

The only thing that `.on('mousedown.inner', ...` does is to namespace your event handler, so that you can remove them by namespace later on, without removing every other `mousedown` handlers on `.wrapper`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ayqqfnm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper').on('mousedown','.inner > .pressy',function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('class'))
    })
```